# Putting a django application on production using IIS Server is raising an error

Tags: python, django, iis

I am trying to put on production a Django web app using IIS Server but I am getting this error:

Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "SGC.wsgi.application" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\SGC\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 92, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'



StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

In my application everything about creditor is installed.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hr.apps.HrConfig',
    'account',
    'courriers',
    'rolepermissions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'admin_tools',
    'cart.apps.CartConfig',
    'enregistrement',
    'ckeditor',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

Here is my web.config file:
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SCG SERVER"
                path="*"
                verb="*"
                modules="FastCgiModule"
                scriptProcessor="c:\programdata\anaconda3\python.exe|c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
                resourceType="Unspecified"
                requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="F:\SGC" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="SGC.wsgi.application" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="SGC.settings" />   
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

For me, I think that the error is related to this line: `raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb)).
Please assist me.

Comment: Could you please tell me your python version?  If possible, please update the ckeditor version to newest version and try again.

Comment: @ Brando Zhang , I am using Python3.6